# How to implement nested namespace in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

```
use level1\level2\level3;
```

Can someone explain with a simple demo ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clear up any confusion regarding different syntax use, namespaces support only two syntaxes, either *bracketed* or *simple-combination* both will work. I suggest if you use one over the other, be consistent.

```
<?php
namespace my\stuff\nested {  // <- bracketed syntax
 class foo {}
}
?>
```

It creates a class `foo` inside of the `nested` namespace with *bracketed syntax* (`{}`), it is equivalent to

```
<?php
namespace my\stuff {  // bracketed syntax but with a nested look
  namespace nested {
     class foo {}
  }
}
?>
```

You can also use nested namespaces with *simple-combination syntax* (`;`)

```
<?php
namespace mine;
use ultra\long\ns\name;  // <- simple-combination syntax

$a = name\CONSTANT;
name\func();
?>
```

[**PHP: FAQ: things you need to know about namespaces**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.nested)

Comment: Seems `{}` after namespace is not necessary?

Comment: Nope, it is not necessary. It show how you can create a class inside of a namespace, hence the `{}`

Comment: So the only functionality of `use` is a shorthand?

Comment: Its only a shorter notation for `namespace`

Comment: It's interesting that `my\stuff\nested` will work even if `my\stuff` doesn't exist.Is this a bug?

Comment: Nope its not a bug, you actually *are* declaring the namespace `my\stuff`

Comment: When you type in your code `hey\whats\up` as a namespace, you are declaring the namespace to be `hey\whats\up`, regardless of whether `hey` or `whats` exists or does not exist. It is more of a hierarchy approach. So inside of that namespace if I were to initialize a constant called `Dude`, I would access that constant by `hey\whats\up\Dude`.