# PHP: using sub-namespace class inside a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, name-collision

Suppose I have a top-level namespace `\Outer`
and I have another sub-namespace `\Outer\Inner`
and I have another top-level namespace `\Inner`

and in a class in `\Outer` I use `Inner` like this

```
use Inner;
```

then which Inner will be used?

```
\Outer\Inner // ( sub-namespace )
```

or the

```
\Inner  // ( top-level namespace )
```

I am confused because php said that the `\` was optional for top-level namespaces?

Comment: `use Inner` and `use \Inner` both are different. First one is sub-namespace of Outer namespace but later one is top-level namespace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement nested namespace in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230025/how-to-implement-nested-namespace-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

When you have namespace `\Outer` in a class, then `use Inner` is going to be using `Inner` top-level namespace. If you want to use subnamespace you should use
`\Outer\Inner`

As stated in php [using namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Lets say your first file was:

```
<?php
namespace Outer\Inner;
```

---

```
<?php
 namespace Outer;

/* Qualified name */
Inner\foo(); // resolves to function Outer\Inner\foo
```