# Dynamic declaration of a model in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to create an instance of a model dynamically. Is this possible with yii2?

I am trying something like this

```
    <?php

namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException; 
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;


use app\models; 


class SintelComponent extends Component
{

public function find($model_name, $id) 
{
    $magic = __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$model_name; //__NAMESPACE__ is a magic constant
    if (($model = $magic::findOne($id)) !== null) 
    {
        return $model;
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
}
```

$model_name is the name of the model. When i try this i get an error like this

> syntax error, unexpected '$model_name' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: see [Namespaces FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.quote)

Answer (score 1):

I will not be able to test this (I'm on my phone), but can you try doing it like this:

```
public function find($model_name, $id) 
{
    $_model = '\app\\models\\'.$model_name;
    if (($model = $_model::findOne($id)) !== null) 
    {
        return $model;
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Comment: i got an error like this Call to a member function findOne() on a non-object when i tried it.

Comment: please see my edit, I think `models` should have two `\` before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
namespace app\models; 
public function find($model_name, $id) 
{
    $magic = __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$model_name; //__NAMESPACE__ is a magic constant
    if (($model = $magic::findOne($id)) !== null) 
    {
        return $model;
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

**Note:** Works for current namespace only.

Comment: i tried as u said but i get a Class 'app\components\Organizations' not found error.

Comment: @Bloodhound.  you can access only one namespace , if you use it inside component then your namespace will be `app\components`.

Comment: @Bloodhound. You also need `php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php`

Comment: so i wont be able to do the dynamic model declaration? @Insane Skull

Comment: @Bloodhound. Probably yes, but you can try multiple namespaces , told you in my previous comment.

Comment: @Bloodhound. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230025/how-to-implement-nested-namespace-in-php

Comment: what i am trying to do is not possible.

Comment: @Bloodhound. may be, one option left is nested namespace. others i don't know.